# DataSet Java Implementation?

Tags: java, datatable, dataset, swingx

I am trying to implement the DataSet type as described in the oracle docs [here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/dataset/DataSet.html) to later be implemented with a DataTable as described [here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/dataset/DataTable.html). However, I can not seem to find the right library nor the right way to implement this datatype. Any help would be appreciated as every import I try doesn't know what the type is and I have tried to add the swingx library in addition but to no avail.Just as a note, I have tried the swingx library from [here](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases). However, even with added the import manually it still doesn't know this type. Is it possible the package changed since it looks like that documentation is from 0.8 when the library itself is much later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.jdesktop.DataSet` is part of the SwingLabs API, whose website you can find from **[here](https://swingx.java.net/)**.

The releases are located under [downloads](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases).

**Edit:**

I think I found a more complete package of the SwingLabs API... At the very least it should contain the dataset package. Link **[here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/)**

Comment: Ok ya that is the one I did try. I downloaded their .jar binary and added it to my project as an external lib but it still doesn't know what DataSet. I even tried manually doing the import but it couldn't find it even with org.jdesktop.*

Comment: @Kyle funny, apparently dataset package is not included in that library. I'll look into it